# select second lowest date in group

Tags: r

I want to select the second lowest DATE grouped per ID (if more than one DATE) and then mutate the result into an new column (NEW).

```
DF<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~DATE,
   1L, "2001-01-01",
   2L, "2002-02-02",
   2L, "2002-02-02",
   3L, "2004-04-04",
   3L, "2005-05-05",
   4L, "2006-06-06",
   4L, "2006-06-06",
   4L, "2007-07-07"
  )

# A tibble: 8 × 2
     ID DATE      
  <int> <chr>     
1     1 2001-01-01
2     2 2002-02-02
3     2 2002-02-02
4     3 2004-04-04
5     3 2005-05-05
6     4 2006-06-06
7     4 2006-06-06
8     4 2007-07-07
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
     ID DATE       NEW       
  <int> <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2001-01-01 NA        
2     2 2002-02-02 NA        
3     2 2002-02-02 NA        
4     3 2004-04-04 2005-05-05
5     3 2005-05-05 2005-05-05
6     4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
7     4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
8     4 2007-07-07 2007-07-07
```

Best regards,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `unique` to only consider unique dates when selecting the second date.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, DATE) %>%
  mutate(NEW = unique(DATE)[2])
```

**Output**

```
     ID DATE       NEW       
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2001-01-01 NA        
2     2 2002-02-02 NA        
3     2 2002-02-02 NA        
4     3 2004-04-04 2005-05-05
5     3 2005-05-05 2005-05-05
6     4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
7     4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
8     4 2007-07-07 2007-07-07
```

Comment: I have the similar question but when I ran the code till arrange part, it works. But when I added the mutate(new=unique(date)[2]), it seems the r only put the correct value for the first id and paste it through the whole column. It looks like that the result was not calculated within group anymore, do you also happen to know what kind of issue for that? Thanks~~!

Comment: thanks for your reply, Ben. It turns out that when the r attached with plyr, the group_by does not work correctly. I referred another post and detached plyr, then it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just throw out the `unique`s, i.e. `length(unique(x)) == 1`.

```
transform(DF, NEW=ave(DATE, ID, FUN=\(x) {
  if (NROW(x) == 1 || length(unique(x)) == 1)  NA
  else x[order(as.Date(x)) == 2]
}))
#   ID       DATE        NEW
# 1  1 2001-01-01       <NA>
# 2  2 2002-02-02       <NA>
# 3  2 2002-02-02       <NA>
# 4  3 2004-04-04 2005-05-05
# 5  3 2005-05-05 2005-05-05
# 6  4 2006-06-06 2006-06-06
# 7  4 2006-06-06 2006-06-06
# 8  4 2007-07-07 2006-06-06
```

For the rest, using `ave` and `order` with case handling to produce NA's like in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479065/6574038).

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
setDT(DF)[order(ID, DATE), NEW := nth(unique(DATE), 2), by = ID]
```

-output

```
> DF
   ID       DATE        NEW
1:  1 2001-01-01       <NA>
2:  2 2002-02-02       <NA>
3:  2 2002-02-02       <NA>
4:  3 2004-04-04 2005-05-05
5:  3 2005-05-05 2005-05-05
6:  4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
7:  4 2006-06-06 2007-07-07
8:  4 2007-07-07 2007-07-07
```